# How apply scalaz.EitherT.fromEither to scalaz.\/?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I am trying to adapt my code from that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257060/combining-futures-eithers-and-options-in-for-comprehensions). Everything is good, except that my methods returns `scalaz.\/` instead of `scala.util.Either`. So for now I have to write a monkey code like that:

```
def myFunction:Future[LeftBad \/ RightGood] = ...

val result = for {
    x <- fromEither(myFunction.map(_.toEither))
} yield {
  ...
}
result.run
//etc
```

Is there a way to construct `EitherT` from `Future[\/]` without `toEither` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`EitherT.eitherT(...)`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.EitherT$) or just [`EitherT(...)`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.EitherT):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val futDisjunction: Future[String \/ Int] = Future.successful(\/-(5))

scala> EitherT(futDisjunction)
// scalaz.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,Int]
```

Comment: Both variants work, but in case of `EitherT(...)` intellij idea can not figure types. :( But nevertheless code work after sbt build. :)