# Scala: Conditional guard in for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, filter, guard

I need some enlightenment about the guard in a for loop in Scala: my code is

```
for {
  enterprise <- itr
  preferName <- enterprise \* qpreferedName
  variantName <- enterprise \* qvariantName
  attrVRes <- enterprise \* qtype \@ attrRes
  if (text(preferName).contains(keyword) || text(variantName).contains(keyword))
} {
//loop code
}
```

Now it works file. But I want to check the value of `keyword`, if it's an empty string, I will not apply this guard (`if (text(preferName).contains(keyword) || text(variantName).contains(keyword))`), otherwise apply it.

Can someone tell me a decent way to do it?

Comment: I would suggest looking at this [example](http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/scala-compose-option-future) or this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257060/combining-futures-eithers-and-options-in-for-comprehensions) for a better approach using Monads.

Comment: Unrelated style note: for whatever reason, the guard conditions in for-comprehensions and pattern matching don't require enclosing parens. I'm not sure why this is inconsistent with vanilla if statements, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define such utility

```
def textContains(str: String): String => Boolean = str match {
  case "" => Function.const(true)
  case _ => text(_).contains(str)
}
```

and use it as

```
for {
 /* ... */
if Seq(preferName,variantName).exists(textContains(keyword))
} yield ???
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that `keyword` is defined outside of the for comprehension, I would set up a boolean out there, then add it into the guard. Eg:

```
val keywordInvalid = keyword.isEmpty // Or however you want to define your condition

for {
  enterprise <- itr
  preferName <- enterprise \* qpreferedName
  variantName <- enterprise \* qvariantName
  attrVRes <- enterprise \* qtype \@ attrRes
  if keywordInvalid || text(preferName).contains(keyword) || text(variantName).contains(keyword)
} {
  //loop code
}
```

Or flip it (as per @Łukasz's comment):

```
val keywordValid = keyword.nonEmpty 
...
for {
  ...
  if keywordValid && ((text(preferName).contains(keyword) || text(variantName).contains(keyword))
} {
  //loop code
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it's the first code I thought of, but it doesn't work, if keyword is empty, I got no output then. But my idea is to get all output if keyword is empty.